# cannot get attribute from List<Object> - Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, get, attributes

In **Class1** we have a method `doGet` and a method that returns a List with objects whom type is Animal.

```
public List<Animal> getAnimals()
```

so I call method like:

```
List<Animal> animal = getAnimals();
request.setAttribute("animal_list", animal);
```

In **Class 2** i have a method doGet too, and i want to take animal_list. My code is :

```
List<Animal> list500=request.getAttribute("animal_list");
```

but when I compile I get the message

```
"Object cannot be converted to List<Animal>"
```

Comment: you need to cast the return type of `getAttribute` function , `List<Animal> list500 = (ArrayList<Animal>)request.getAttribute("animal_list");`

Comment: I tried this one, but when I compile I get the message "the file is uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Tool completed successfully"

Answer (score 4):

a cast from `Object` to `List<Animal>` is necessary here:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 List<Animal> list500= (ArrayList<Animal>)request.getAttribute("animal_list");
```

`request.getAttribute` returns just `Object` so you have to define the exact type via `cast`. `Object` could be everything...

as a side node: you will get a

> "Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList"

warning from the `compiler`. In this case you can add

> "suppress the warning"

`annotation`. After that the warning will disappear.

Comment: I tried this one, but when I compile I get the message "the file is uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Tool completed successfully"

Comment: I wrote List<Animal> list500= (ArrayList<Animal>)request.getAttribute("animal_list"); , but the message is "the file is uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Tool completed successfully